# When is it overkill to check the arguments of a function?

Tags: javascript

Is it overkill to check the arguments of a function before carrying on?

E.g.

```
var doFoo = function(id, message){
     // Are these asserts overkill?
     goog.asserts.assertNumber(id, "Expecting a numeric id.");
     goog.asserts.assertString(message, "Expecting a string.");

    // Do more stuff here
}
```

*Note: This is using the closure library's assert statements, but any similar logic could use any library or no library at all, you get the idea.*

EDIT: I guess this question is subjective. A better question would be... **When is it overkill to check the arguments of a function?** I think.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on how safe your more stuff is. But in most cases no. Its definitly no overkill when writing into a database directly (but this check should be server-site). There shouldn't be any trustable client-side code, so when you use it with a server, its alwayse overkill, bekause the check is server-sidet

Comment: Thanks. Although I've updated the question though to make it less likely to get an 'it depends' answer.